# Defining a function in derived class without declaring in the base class

Tags: c++, derived-class

I saw some examples like in the base class function is declared as pure function (as virtual) and in the derived class it is declared (as virtual) and implemented. In the second case (which I am currently doing), base class does not declare the function and only derived class declare (not virtual) and implement. What is the difference between these two options?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case (and by the way the virtual declaration in the derived class is superfluous - virtualisation is inherited), a pointer `Base* p = new Derived()` can be used to call `p->the function`.

In the second case, you could not call the function using `p`. You could only use `Derived* pp = new Derived()` then `pp->the function`.

Answer (score 0):

If the base class doesn't declare a function at all, then that function cannot be called through the base class's type. Example:

```
struct Base1
{
  virtual ~Base1() {}

  virtual void foo() const = 0;
};


struct Derived1 : Base1
{
  virtual void foo() const override { std::cout << "Foo!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  Base1 *p = new Derived1();
  p->foo();  // Works fine
  delete p;
}
```

Vs.

```
struct Base2
{
  virtual ~Base2() {}
};


struct Derived2 : Base2
{
  virtual void foo() const { std::cout << "Foo!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  Base2 *p = new Derived2();
  p->foo();  // Compiler error: no foo() in Base2
  delete p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first case you have **polimorphism** and in the second case you have no it.

Consider the following example

The first case

```
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
   virtual void f() const = 0;
   virtual ~B() {}
};


struct D1
{
   void f() const { std::cout << "It's me, D1!" << std::endl; }
};


struct D2
{
   void f() const { std::cout << "No, it's me, D2!" << std::endl; }
};


void g( const B &b )
{
   b.f();
}

int main()
{
   D1 d1;
   g( d1 );

   D2 d2;
   g( d2 );
}
```

And the second case

```
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
};


struct D1
{
   void f() const { std::cout << "It's me, D1!" << std::endl; }
};


struct D2
{
   void f() const { std::cout << "No, it's me, D2!" << std::endl; }
};


void g( const B &b )
{
   // b.f(); // compilation error
}


void g1( const D1 &d1 )
{
   d1.f();
}

void g2( const D2 &d2 )
{
   d2.f();
}

int main()
{
   D1 d1;
   g1( d1 );
   g( d1 ); // function f will not be called
   //g2( d1 ); // compilation error

   D2 d2;
   g2( d2 );
   g( d2 ); // function f will not be called
   //g1( d2 ); // compilation error
}
```